# I need to restructure a InertiaJS build WebApp to become PWA and I dont know how much reengineering is needed

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, progressive-web-apps, inertiajs

My current project runs on Laravel 10 + VueJs3 + InertiaJs1.x.

The project is 70% finished and I had never the intention to build it as a PWA. But now a change came in and it seems that I should convert it to PWA.

To the project structure:

Laravel as a standard Backend (started with Breeze), but doing the routing logic (ziggy), as it is recommended with Inertia. Laravel has no API Calls set up, as I am passing InertiaResponses to Vue.

When I go over the PWA documentation, the setup between Front and Back is always over RestAPIs and respectively the Axios Calls.

Here is where I get confused, because I don’t know if setting up a manifest and Worker will interfere with Inertia. Google is giving me contradicting advice.

I may add that the only reason to leverage PWA is the Offline mode. No need for GPS, Push or similar.

I posted this question in Reddit as well, but I think this place is more appropriate.

Anybody here with this experience and could you point me to the right path to continue?

Thx!